# New Coke was a conspiracy to boost sales of Classic Coke

Tags: marketing, drink

It is claimed that New Coke was a [conspiracy to boost sales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Coke#Conspiracy_theories) of Classic Coke.

> The company intentionally changed the formula, hoping consumers would be upset with the company, and demand the original formula to return, which in turn would cause sales to spike.

Is there any evidence for this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the claim? How would this "conspiracy" work?

Comment: @Sklivvz, Here is a list of [conspiracy theories about new coke on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Coke#Conspiracy_theories). The main reason it is claimed that it is true was because classic coke had a massive increase in sales after new coke was phased out, and Pepsi basically made no gains.

Comment: They needed time to remove the Coca from the cola.

Comment: @Thomas O:Conspiracy implies there was a crime(or intention of a crime). This would be a marketing startegy.

Comment: @apoorv020, good point, but it's still a "conspiracy theory" because people are "conspiring" to hide truth. N.B. I don't actually accept this theory (I think it was just a marketing screw up which turned out good for Coke), but I was told it by a friend of mine...

Comment: @apoorv020: No, most conspiracy theories are not about crimes. A conspiracy in this sense is group of people who are surreptitiously trying to achieve a secret goal that is different or opposite from their publicly stated aims.

Comment: I would almost consider new coke to be a crime. Although perhaps not as bad as Crystal Pepsi

Comment: Let's not argue about definitions :-) Wikipedia calls it a conspiracy theory so I think we can accept it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Snopes debunked it.

http://www.snopes.com/cokelore/newcoke.asp

In short: Sales of Coke was waning, and Pepsi was winning. So Coca Cola changed the recipe to be more like Pepsi and made a big campaign about the new recipe. This got people upset, as they felt it violated something that was an integral part of being American. People therefore demanded the old Coke back, which they got after a couple of months. The whole debacle made people who felt American switch from Pepsi to Coke, and boosted Coke sales.

The conspiracy is that all of this was *intentional* from Coca Colas side, which of course is completely ridiculous.

Additional reference: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b010tbnd

Comment: Snipes does not provide any reference for this. Can you?

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page. It provides sources there.

Comment: Snopes is USELESS. It has ZERO credibility.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Look at the bottom of the page. It provides sources there.